Will MSP 2019 add-ins work in Project Online Desktop Client?
I have an add-in that works in Microsoft Project Professional 2019. Will this same add-in work in Microsoft Project Online Desktop Client?
I installed the add-in on a PC that has Project Online Desktop Client installed. The installation went through with no errors and I can see the add-in in installled programs. However, when I open Project Online Desktop Client the add-in does not show.

MS Project Add-ins, particularly COM add-ins (which is what I believe you are referring to) will indeed work in the MS Project Online Desktop Client. Add-ins will not work in the web-based version of MS Project, that is to say if you are working with Project in a web browser, your add-ins will not be accessible there.
As long as you are working with a desktop client of MS Project, any version 2010 and above will support add-ins. Most everyone exclusively uses the desktop client to build and manage their project schedules.
